# Sending a value from controller to 'header' view but when page changes the variable is undefined

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sending the values of $data from controller to header but when page changes to another on which header is included it shows error.

Look at the code below

Controller

```
`$user_email=$_GET['email'];
  $this->load->model('Pmodel');

  $data['email']=$this->Pmodel->profile_model($user_email);

   $this->load->view('dashboard/profile',$data);`
```

now header "view"

```
    <?php  foreach ($data as $key ):?>
   <?php   
 $uname=$key['uname'];
 $user_email=$key['email'];
 ?>
    <li>
    <?php echo anchor('user/profile_user/?email='.$user_email, $uname ); ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

but when page changes from dashboard to profile it shows error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: dashboard/header.php

Line Number: 58

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: dashboard/header.php

Line Number: 58

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the keys no loop required.

Like:

```
 <?php   
$uname=$uname;
$user_email=$email;
?>
<li>
  <?php 
      echo anchor('user/profile_user/?email='.$user_email, $uname;
  ?>
</li>
```

Comment: I am using foreach to get more values from my function if i remove it shows error that array to string conversion error

Comment: Please share print_r of data and email and uname

Answer (score 0):

Try this ways..

**use this code in your View**

```
  <?php  foreach ($data as $key ):?>
   <?php   
 $uname=$key['uname'];
 $user_email=$key['email'];
 ?>
    <li>
    <?php echo anchor('user/profile_user/'.$user_email, $uname ); ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and your controller use this code

```
public function profile_user($user_email)
{
   $data =array();
  $this->load->model('Pmodel');

  $data['email']=$this->Pmodel->profile_model($user_email);

   $this->load->view('dashboard/profile',$data);`
}
```

Comment: this is the error  getting A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for User::profile_user(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\P_Display\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 360 and defined

Filename: controllers/user.php

Line Number: 131

Comment: what is you controller  and function name

Answer (score 0):

you send $data['email'] from controller, it means you send `$email` to view instead of`$data`

try this:

```
foreach ($email as $key )
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the data

```
 $data['email']=$this->Pmodel->profile_model($user_email);
```

in every controller and method
.